# How to link multiple columns to 1 variable in Data driven automation of ranorex

Tags: ui-automation, data-driven-tests, ranorex

Consider following example -
There are 2 columns A) Company Name and B) Employee Name.

One Company can have multiple Employee names. So How do perform Data driven automation in this case as it allows only 1 column to link to 1 variable.

e.g. Column 1 = Company Name
Column 2 to 8 = Employee Name

In this case how do I link columns 2 to 8 to only 1 variable

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want the test case to be called once per company and link a list of employees to a variable, or do you want to run it once per employee? In the latter case, I would use 2 columns and use multiple rows per company. E.g. row1: Company A, Employee A1, row2: Company A, Employee A2, row3: Company B: Employee B1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ranorex expects to have a row of a data source as a single test case.  In the case you are describing above you seem to have 7 different test cases? the easy way would be to have the data source have two columns and 7 rows.  so you would have company a in column 1 row 1, employee a in column 2 row 1, company a in column 1 row 2 and employee b in column 2 row 2.  This would give you two different test case runs from your data source.

If on your test case you will always use the same company for all these tests you could bind this to a test suite level variable, and then use a data source with a single column for your data source on your test case.  You could then override the test suite level variable if you need to change the company from the command line when you start your test suite